# Unable to install python on fedora server

Tags: python, linux, fedora

So I am trying to install python on my fedora 36 server using

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.8/Python-3.10.8.tgz
```

but when I run the code it says

```
Error: The certificate of 'www.python.org' is not trusted
```

I am using
`wget` btw

Comment: This would be much better off at superuser.com, since it has nothing to do with actual programming but just with using `wget`. Also, just a suggestion, try to find packaged versions of software instead of building it from scratch, unless you have a specific need.

Answer (score 0):

See wget help:

> **--no-check-certificate**
>
> Don't check the server certificate against the available certificate authorities.  Also don't require the URL host name to
> match the common name presented by the certificate.
>
> As of Wget 1.10, the default is to verify the server's certificate against the recognized certificate authorities, breaking the SSL handshake and aborting the download if the verification fails.  Although this provides more secure downloads, it does break interoperability with some sites that worked with previous Wget versions, particularly those using self-signed, expired, or otherwise invalid certificates.
>
> This option forces an "insecure" mode of operation that turns the certificate verification errors into warnings and allows you to proceed.

So, `wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.8/Python-3.10.8.tgz` could be one option you could try.

Another option maybe install `ca-certificates`, but I never did this in Fedora, you may could have a try with [Adding and trusting a Certificate Authority (CA) in Fedora](https://ajmaradiaga.com/Adding-trusting-CA-Fedora/)

Comment: Where can I find the certificate for python?